# Can't use imported functions in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, canopy

Every time I attempt to run this on Canopy.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

y = np.arange(10.0, 0.0, 0.5)

print(y)
```

I get:

> %run "/var/folders/mw/h485shnx75dg6f4z_xvcg5hm0000gn/T/tmpcjJKuI.py" []

Comment: What's the error? Huh?

Comment: I have no idea. I've never used python before and this just shows up at the bottom every time i try to print the array.

Comment: So when you run that the blockquoted text gets printed? that's weird...

Comment: Yeah exactly, don't know what's wrong.

Comment: What do you mean "run on Canopy"? Canopy is an installation package, not a code interpreter / IDE, as far as I know

Comment: Look, this is my first time using any of this. It says Canopy at the top and I'm using Python 2.7. If anyone knows how to fix this please help.

Answer (score 1):

[**`%run`** is an IPython magic command.](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-run)

`"/var/folders/mw/h485shnx75dg6f4z_xvcg5hm0000gn/T/tmpcjJKuI.py"` is the location of your script on disk. You probably have not saved this to a file anywhere else, hence the random location.

`[]` is the arguments that are passed into the script. You have none, so this is an empty list.

---

All in all, I think you're looking for the output in the wrong place.

Or simply nothing is printed because you have defined  `start=10.0, stop=0.0`, but the step is positive. In other words, you should check the numpy documentation for what you want to accomplish

Comment: So what is the mistake that I am making. How can I print the array? Also, when I attempt to save the file, the run button becomes grey and I cannot run anything.

Comment: I don't know what program you are using to save/run.

Comment: How can I check? I'm using Enthought Canopy and Python 2.7

Comment: What are you trying to print? Values from `10.0` to `0.0`? If so, you need `-0.5`

Comment: For reference, you can run this script to see what should be getting. https://repl.it/L7sP/0

Comment: Yes, that worked, thank you so much. Running the code works but I still get the message: %run "/Users/humzah/Desktop/dsadas.py" at the top. Why does the location of the file show up.

Comment: Because that's how your thing works, apparently. It executes IPython under the hood.

Comment: The 2nd part of this answer is correct: "simply nothing is printed because you have defined  start=10.0, stop=0.0, but the step is positive"

Comment: I recommend that you accept this as the correct answer. I will also explain in another answer, why you are seeing the %run command.

Answer (score 1):

1) The Python panel in the Canopy GUI application is an IPython QtConsole. IPython provides various "magic" commands which can be entered in the Python panel even though they are not actual Python statements. One such magic command is the `%run` command, which will run the specified file. Canopy's "Run" command simply executes the IPython %run command, which is why that command appears in the Python console as soon as you "Run" your file.

You typed your code into the Canopy editor, but you did not save it with a filename. So when you "run" the, it auto-saves as a temporary file, and runs that temporary file, as @cricket_007 points out.

2) As @cricket_007 points out, your `arange` call is incorrect. You have mixed up the order of arguments, so the result is an empty array, which prints as `[]`

I suggest that you do lots of experimentation. You'll learn a lot and you won't break anything.